# Android Saving of Strings

Tags: java, android, string

I'm wanting to save the value of strings (numeral Strings) to somewhere where i can when the user reloads the app, the values can be passed back into the app. Being saved to local storage is preferrable

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use sharedPrefercences or SQLite Database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using shared preferences over a SQLLite DB if you are only saving a small amount of strings.

```
private void saveStringToPreferences(String key, String str){
     SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
     editor.putString(key, str);
     editor.apply();
}

private void getStringFromPreferences(String key){
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String previousText = preferences.getString(key, "");
    return previousText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should do some research before asking such a question.  Here is a link to the options available for  storing data in android:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I've downvoted the question.  I've noticed the last months that users ask for some general problem in the hopes that somebody posts just the puede of code they need!!!  They're soooo daaaaamn laaaazy they cannot even Google for the question